# How to install mikrotik routerOS on my computer

Tags: routing, router, mikrotik

I got a mikrotik routerboard 950G and i downloaded netinstall v6.8 but i cannot install the routerOS into my computer. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routerboards come with MikroTik pre-installed.

Netinstall is a Windows utility that allows you to 'format' a routerboard and do a clean install of Mikrotik RouterOS on it ( [Netinstall](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Netinstall) ).

You would only need to Netinstall Mikrotik onto Routerboard if the installation is broken. Otherwise you could just reset its configuration ([Password reset](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Password_reset)).

If you want to install Mikrotik RouterOS to a PC you don't need the Netinstall utility.

You need the ISO image to burn to a CD, boot from and install (eg: http://download2.mikrotik.com/routeros/6.28/mikrotik-6.28.iso )

Since you mention that you already got a Routerboard I can assume that you don't want to install Mikrotik on your PC, rather connect to Mikrotik from your PC.

To connect to Mikrotik you need Winbox. http://download2.mikrotik.com/routeros/winbox/3.0rc9/winbox.exe

Mikrotik has excellent documentation. I suggest you take a look. You will find almost anything you need [main page of wiki](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Main_Page)

Comment: thans a bunch. I cant express my gratitude in words

Comment: Just for clarification: You don't *need* Winbox to connect to the Mikrotik router, you can also use the webinterface.

Comment: Correct. Also there is a pretty nice CLI via telnet or SSH. I just find Winbox much more usable and intuitive :)

Comment: I want to connect to webfig n i need my routerboard's ip address but i dont know the ip address of my routerboard ... Is there anyway i can get the information from the routerboard

Comment: Yes. Using winbox. On the field where you type the address, on the right there is a square little button. You press it and it will search your LAN for any mikrotik device. Once found it will list its MAC address and its IP (if assigned any).